# Insert to top of collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible in MongoDB to insert a new document to the top of a collection? Normally, when creating new document, it is appended or added to the end of the collection.

Please shed some light

Answer (score 2):

The order in which documents are returned from a collection is undefined behavior. Usually documents appear in the order they are inserted, but you can not rely on that. There are several circumstances which can cause the documents to get returned in a different order.

When you want documents in a specific order, you need to [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) them explicitly when you search for them.

Comment: They do not appear in insert order but in linked list order